# Force LightStreamer work with higher speed

Tags: websocket, lightstreamer

1. I have visited a webpage which uses LightStreamer to shows live data. Looking in ws section of Chrome DevTools, i found that server serves data with rate of around 1.5 k/s. While i have access to client LightStreamer and can subscribe my own subscriptions, is there a way to force server works with higher speed?
   I've searched docs for some kind config or property for this, but i have not found anything.
2. If fields update with different rate - for example some fields are updated per second, some per 30 second and other per minute - Does dividing them into 3 different subscriptions has any impact on speed? I save all the values - changed or not changed- each 10 seconds in db. Thus for 2nd and 3rd part of fields that has not changed during last 10 seconds, Is separating them from 1st part of fields useful for speed of update in 1st part of fields?
   I have checked this in code, and i have seen no difference between merging or splitting fields. Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Splitting fields doesn't have any impact on the update rate.
On the client-side, you have access to two controls that impact the update rate:

- You can request an update frequency for each individual subscription, including unlimited (see [here](https://sdk.lightstreamer.com/ls-web-client/8.0.2/api/Subscription.html#setRequestedMaxFrequency)).
- You can request a maximum bandwidth for the aggregate of all your subscriptions, including unlimited (see [here](https://sdk.lightstreamer.com/ls-web-client/8.0.2/api/ConnectionOptions.html#setRequestedMaxBandwidth)).

But these are just your requests... The server is free to refuse them and put a cap on both frequency and bandwidth, based on the configuration decided by the server owner.

Comment: Thanks @Alessandro.  I tried them. first one does not work in my case. But in second solution, i tried changing that while connection is active, but see no change. Thus, i tried disconnecting connection, then setting MaxBandwith in ConnectionOptions (and verifying new value by checking getter method) and finally calling connect() method. Unfortunately, after connect(), i see that getter of MaxBandwidth returns old value. Checking messages sent to server for establishing new connection, anything similar to Bandwidth between them. what i'm doing wrong in this way?

Comment: This probably means frequency and/or bandwidth are constrained on the server-side and you can't force a change from the client-side.